# Android listview frequntly make request

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

In my Android Application, I am using PulltoRefresh Library listview ([library url](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshGridView.java)). For now I have implemented footer loader concept(loads data when the listview reaches footer) to load data from server.

But I need to make continous request till I receive the whole data once my activity created(i.e. when I receive first 20 data, I need to request server to pull the next 20 data and it will go on).

Could some one tell me is there any method or listener to call simultaneously without user interaction.

Comment: why are you getting only first 20 elements instead of complete data? Please explain.

Comment: 20 is just an offset value.It might be 10,15,etc.. Instead of using footerloader, I want to load all data asynchronously and at the same time any user can view a particular data before all the data loads in listview

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some thing like this.
First call your main AsyncTask and on post execute set adapter and check

```
if(list.size() == offset)
{
    loadmore = true;
    offset += offset;
} else {
    loadmore = false;
}
```

and in same postExecute function if boolean loadmore is true then call AsyncTask again but this time use notifyDataSetChanges instead of setting adapter in postExecute  and repeat the whole process again.
Offset can be 20 or what ever according to your need. You can have two different AsyncTask  or single one with some flags accordingly. This way data will download automatically untill it ends and you don't need to set adapter every time.